# How to find a certain coefficient from a series that is given by a generating function of two variables?

Tags: generating-functions

How to find the coefficient of $x^1y^3$ from the series that is given by the $\frac{x y}{(y-1) (x+y-2)}$?

The coefficient is according to Wolfram Mathematica $\text{SeriesCoefficient}\left[\frac{x y}{(y-1) (x+y-2)},\{x,0,1\},\{y,0,3 \}\right]=\frac{7}{8}$.

The function is from [the article](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Epg2113/index_files/Gorroochurn-Thirteen%20correct%20solutions%20to%20the%20%E2%80%9CProblem%20of%20Points%E2%80%9D%20and%20their%20histories.pdf) dealing with the Problem of Points - page 61, left column in the middle.

I found a lot of articles about how to find out g.f. for a series. But nothing clear (to me) about how to find out the series from a g. f. of two variables. There seems to be a procedure for one variable that starts with dividing into partial fractions. I guess I understand that division, but probably not very well, because I can't use it with two variables.

I know how to enumerate/calculate result using the original method (which is listed first in the article (Method of Enumeration) and also many times on the Internet). But I am interested in the procedure to find out the coefficient from the g.f.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Any ideas from your side?

Comment: In this specific case $[x^1y^3]\frac{x y}{(y-1) (x+y-2)}=[x^0y^2]\frac{1}{(y-1) (x+y-2)}=[y^2]\frac{1}{(y-1) (y-2)}$

Comment: Thanks @Sil . It seems that your simplification can be applied to this as well:
$[x^1y^2z^2]\frac{x y z}{(1-x) (1-z) (3-x-y-z)}=[y^1z^1]\frac{1}{(1-z) (3-y-z)}$

Comment: The power series of an analytic function is its Taylor series at the origin; you can always extract one particular coefficient by taking partial derivatives etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can more or less use the tools from univariate case by extracting coefficients individually, i.e. $[x^my^n]f(x,y)=[y^n]([x^m]f(x,y))$. So for your function:

\begin{align}
[x^my^n]\frac{x y}{(1-y) (2-y-x)}
&=[y^n]\left([x^m]\frac{x y}{(1-y) (2-y-x)}\right) \\
&=[y^n]\left(\frac{y}{(1-y)(2-y)}[x^m]\frac{x}{(1-\frac{x}{2-y})}\right) \\
&=[y^n]\left(\frac{y}{(1-y)(2-y)}[x^m]\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{i}}{(2-y)^{i-1}}\right) \tag{1}\\
&=[y^n]\frac{y}{(1-y)(2-y)^m} \\
&=\frac{1}{2^m}[y^n]\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\cdot\left(1-\frac{y}{2}\right)^{-m}\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{2^m}[y^n]\left(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}y^i\cdot\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{-m}{j}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^jy^j\right) \tag{2} \\
&=\frac{1}{2^m}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{-m}{j}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^j \tag{3} \\
&=\frac{1}{2^m}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{m-j-1}{j}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^j \tag{4} \\
\end{align}

where:

1. [Infinite geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)
2. [Binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)
3. Extracting product coefficient using [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product)
4. $\binom{-m}{j}(-1)^j=\frac{-m(-m-1)\cdots(-m-j+1)}{j!}(-1)^j=\frac{(m+j-1)\cdots(m+1)m}{j!}=\binom{m+j-1}{j}$

So in your example $m=1,n=3$ we have
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(\binom{0}{0}+\binom{1}{1}\frac{1}{2}+\binom{2}{2}\frac{1}{4}\right)=\frac{7}{8}.
$$